# Regex to find specific text between specific parentheses

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm trying to build a Oracle query with `REGEXP_LIKE` to find all records that contains the number 68 within the parentheses after the word "something": `something:(...)`

So the following strings should match my search:

- other:(45 or 1) something:(78 or 68 or 5)
- something:(68 or 5) thing:(57)
- some:(888) something:(68) thing:(57)

These strings should **not** match my search:

- something:(5) thing:(68)
- something:(**668**)

I'm trying this:

```
^.*?something:\((.*68.*)\).*$
```

But that is searching 68 until the end of the text and matching 668 as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check what your regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?something:\(` - any 0+ chars up to the first occurrence of
- `(.*68.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars as many as possible, `68` (*so it can be matched when enclosed with other digits!*) and then again any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\)` - a literal `)`
- `.*` - again any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

As you see it relies heavily on a very inefficient `.*` pattern and does not prevent matching `68` in `1236835`.

What you need to achieve is to only match `68` in the following positions:

- after `(` or after `(` followed with any number of chars other than `)` and right after a non-digit (that is also a non-`(`)
- but before a `)` or before a non-digit and non-`)` followed with any 0+ chars other than `)` and followed with `)`.

This pattern can be written as

```
something:\(([^)]*[^0-9)])?68([^0-9)][^)]*)?\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5lZEFK/2)

Also, see my [Oracle tests](http://rextester.com/QMIJCQ91529).

**Details**

- `something:\(`  - a literal `something:(` substring
- `([^)]*[^0-9)])?` - an optional sequence of patterns:

  - `[^)]*` - 0+ chars other than `)`
  - `[^0-9)]` - a char other than a digit and `)`
- `68` - a literal value
- `([^0-9)][^)]*)?` - an optional sequence of patterns:

  - `[^0-9)]` - a char other than a digit and `)`
  - `[^)]*` - 0+ chars other than `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

Comment: It worked, thanks Wictor! One thing I didn't understand though: `([^)]*[^0-9)])?`... so this is looking for 0+ char other than `)`... **AND** 1 char other than digit followed by `)`? So the second part is requiring a char before 68?

Comment: @qxlab `([^)]*[^0-9)])?` is an optional capturing group `(...)?` that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the sequence of patterns inside the group. It matches 0+ chars other than `)` followed with any char but a digit and `)` - that is, `68` is either preceded with `(` or `(...[NON-DIGIT and NON-)]`.